# Load listener-class in standalone Java using main()

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml

Is there a way I can keep listening to certain Servlet listener-class using standalone java program?

**snippet(web.xml) - will not be used in standalone:**

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>
    com.yourpackage.MyServletContext
  </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Or any alternative way to implement this `web.xml` listener-class in standalone programs?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean... without tomcat? Using java HttpServer?

Comment: Yes, something like that. I want to start a process in standalone mode using `main()` method and want to keep listening to that class `com.yourpackage.MyServletContext` class.